# Slack token verification returning two seperate signatures?

Tags: python, authentication, slack-api, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to validate my Slack bot using the example code provided in the Slack documentation [here](https://api.slack.com/authentication/verifying-requests-from-slack). However, it is returning two different signatures.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # get slack secret from secrets manager
    secret = get_secret()
    # needed for creating hmac
    qstring = base64.b64decode(event['body']).decode('utf-8')
    return validate_request(secret, qstring, event['headers'])

# get slack secret for verification from secrets manager
def get_secret():
    secret_name = "<omitted>"
    region_name = "<omitted>"
    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'DecryptionFailureException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InternalServiceErrorException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidParameterException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'InvalidRequestException':
            raise e
        elif e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'ResourceNotFoundException':
            raise e
    else:
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            return get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
        else:
            return base64.b64decode(get_secret_value_response['SecretBinary'])
           
# validate bot request
def validate_request(secret, body, headers):
    timestamp = headers['x-slack-request-timestamp']
    sig_basestring = 'v0:' + timestamp + ':' + body
    my_signature = 'v0=' + hmac.new(secret.encode('utf_8'), sig_basestring.encode('utf_8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    slack_signature = headers['x-slack-signature']
    if hmac.compare_digest(my_signature, slack_signature):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Result:

```
v0=24dde133843073b58084970afe027e3a4dabc1b8d9efc5248a97ad64c6529cee
v0=bf51d6fb9eb56d5c6ea19e866b798903fb0cee67264cb467ee7924bb13571770
```

Any ideas why? I've verified that the correct token is returned by `get_secret()` and that the `qstring` variable contains the correct query parameters as shown in Slack's documentation. The headers all contain the correct values too.

Answer (score 0):

For me the signatures were different because I was formatting the body received from slack request to json before passing to the verify function.

Passing the body as it is resolved my issue.

Format of body to be passed to verify function-

'body': 'token=XXXXXXXXXX&team_id=XXXXXXX&team_domain=XXXXXX&channel_id=XXXXX&channel_name=XXXXXX&user_id=XXX&user_name=XXXX&command=XXXXX&text=XXXX&api_app_id=XXXXXX&is_enterprise_install=false&response_url=XXXXX&trigger_id=XXXXXXXX'

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else still stuck. In my case I was using the body as sent in the in the post. That's a base64 encoded string. That had to be decoded before using it in the signature.

In my case this was what did it (`event` because I'm sending it to a lamda):

```
import base64

body            = base64.b64decode(encoded_body).decode('utf-8')
timestamp       = post['headers']['X-Slack-Request-Timestamp']
concat_message  = ('v0:' + timestamp + ':' + body).encode()
key             = 'YOUR-SLACK-SERCRET'.encode()
hashed_msg      = 'v0=' + hmac.new(key, concat_message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

slack_signature = post['headers']['X-Slack-Signature']

if (hashed_msg != slack_signature):
    return{
        'statusCode': 403,
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'body': json.dumps('Forbidden')
    }
```